# Leer archivo Excel con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, http, phpexcel

Buenas, Necesito  crear un formulario donde los usuarios puedan subir un archivo xlsx, y el la app web validar el archivo luego leerlo, y por ultimo necesito meter la información luego de evaluarla en una base de datos, estoy usando una libreria PHPExcel, el problema esta en que me da error en la pagina, Cuando coloco el archivo xlsx que va leer me marca error en la web, (Esta pagina no funciona) HTTP ERROR 500. Debugeando, no es error de ruta ya que fui colocando rutas una por una, y colocaba el nombre del archivo mal para testear y me daba el catch, de error que el archivo no existe, pero cuando coloco la ruta de manera correcta, PAM me da error.

```js
require_once('../phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
require_once('../phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php');
require_once '../phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php'; 
$inputFileName = '../phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/jd.xlsx';
try {
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
echo '<table>' . "\n";
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
echo '<tr>' . "\n";
$cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
$cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // This loops all cells,
foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
echo '<td>' . $cell->getValue() . '</td>' . "\n";
}
 
echo '</tr>' . "\n";
}
echo '</table>' . "\n";
} catch(Exception $e) {
 die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}


echo '<hr />';
echo "<pre>";
```

```js
Result : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: ¿Seguro que todos los `require_once...` existen en las rutas que estás indicando? ¿No hay más detalles del error en el log? Puede deberse también a un problema de exceso de memoria usada en el procesamiento del archivo xls...

Comment: Si, y no quiero pensar que sea una ruta interna de la libreria, Soy nuevo  en el uso de esta libreria

Comment: Pero el error 500 es lo que recibes del lado del cliente. Tendrías que revisar el log de errores del lado del servidor para obtener un trace del error

Comment: Para ir depurando si el Excel que intentas usar es muy grande prueba con un Excel pequeño con una sola hoja y dos o tres filas. Si funciona entonces el origen del error sería exceso de memoria. Para ver el log de errores del lado del servidor puedes hacerlo entrando a tus archivos de servidor vía sftp o desde cPanel. El archivo errorlog suele estar en la misma carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo PHP en cuestión.

Answer (score 1):

Verifica la ruta de la libreria, y tambien mencionar que no es necesario agregar todos esos include que tienes en tu codigo, basta con incluir `IOFactory.php`.

```
require_once 'php/ext/PHPExcel-1.7.7/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
//cargamos el archivo que deseamos leer
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($nombreArchivo);
//obtenemos los datos de la hoja activa (la primera)
$objHoja=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);

foreach ($objHoja as $iIndice=>$objCelda) 
{
  echo $objCelda['B'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero revises tu archivo log de errores, ya que tu ejemplo funciona bien en un protoipo que he creado en mi localhost. (Si no puedes hallar la ubicacion de tu log de errores, indicame tu Sistema Operativo y te daré instrucciones de como hallarlo).

También recuerda que para usar PHPExcel, necesitas tener PHP version 5.2.0 o superior y tener configuradas las siguientes extensiones:

- php_zip (para manejar .xlsx .ods o .gnumeric)
- php_xml
- php_gd2 (opcional, pero requerido para autocalcular el ancho de las columnas).

Esto lo puedes verificar con phpinfo

Saludos.

Comment: Revise el log de errores en mi cpanel y solo salen los log antiguos, ni siquiera me manda un error esto que estoy preguntando, lo curioso es que intente con otra libreria, y me pasaba lo mismo, yo creo que es por lo que me indicas que tengo que instalar esos paquetes

Comment: Estoy trabajando con php 5.2.0, realmente es todo muy extraño

Comment: Sal de dudas.

En tu cPANEL debes de tener la opción PHPINFO. 

Verifica allí la existencia de los módulos "zip", "xml" y "gd"